# Way to create an event?

Tags: solidity, remix, events

As soon as a function is called this other function should also be called!!

Example: As soon as ether is deposited it should transfer funds into employees wallet.

I already have functions deposit() and transferFunds() ready. Just need a way so that as soon as deposit is called transfer should also happen.

**Not this though:::**

I don't want to call one function inside other functions!!!!

deposit()

{

transferFunds();

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As those both functions are in the same contract you simply have to call the other function inside `deposit`. Also if you want to receive Ethers with the `deposit` function it has to be marked `payable`. So something like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0; 

contract MyContract {    
    function deposit() payable external {
        // do some stuff
        transferFunds();
    }
    function transferFunds() private {
        // do the transfer
    }
}
```

Comment: but what if I wanted to create an event and then do it.

Comment: smart contracts can't detect events. Events are something which can be read only from outside the blockchain - so they are used for giving information to a outside-the-blockchain system

Comment: ohh okay that helps understanding it better. Thanks

Comment: If you find an answer helpful please upvote it and if the answer solves your problem you should also mark it as accepted

Comment: Oh! okay sure! Will keep that in mind!

Comment: It's a way of showing other users what helped so they know what they can try if they have the same problem.